# mysqldump: Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file '*.txt' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions

Linux. No SELinux (disabled).
I try to run this command as my linuxuser (member of group mysql):

`mysqldump --user=root --tab "/some/folder" dbname`

Getting this error:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file 'sometable.txt' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'`

If I look in the folder, there is a `sometable.sql` file, but no txt file.
As I understand, the sql file is created from the user's name who run the command (linuxuser in my case), but the txt file gets generated by mysql server (mysql user in this case). Note that mysql user is also a member of mysql group.

What could be the problem? Tried everything :)

Comment: This is probably a simple permissions issue which you can confirm by `chmod 777 /some/folder` If mysql still can't write the data files check the parent directory permissions.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think it was due to parent folder permissions.

Answer (score 2):

If you trying to execute a mysqldump in a client diferent that the server
can be a problem
I tried with mysqldump Ver 10.14 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64), and works only with the /tmp/ dir.
Perhaps, help info say that will not work

```
  -T, --tab=name      Create tab-separated textfile for each table to given path. (Create .sql and .txt files.) NOTE: This only works if mysqldump is run on the same machine as the mysqld server.
```

Comment: It does not work remotely in any version of MySQL. The tabular option uses OUTFILE which writes to a file on disk. So unless you have a file/directory on your host machine mounted or otherwise "pointed" to a disk on your client machine, eg. with NFS, you can't dump to the client with the -T option.

Answer (score 2):

This was something I just found and wanted to pass along for the folks searching for the same answer.

This has been occurring on systems running systemd. In the /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service file is the setting, 'PrivateTmp=true'. This is a security measure to prevent the data from being seen by folks who shouldn't be seeing it.

If you run:

```
SELECT * TO OUTFILE '/var/tmp/tablename.txt' FROM TABLENAME;
```

It will create the file but it creates it in a systemd protected directory.

/var/tmp/systemd-private-[hash]-mariadb-[hash]/tmp/tablename.txt

You can either save the data from here which is perfectly acceptable or stop mariadb, create the directory /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d and in that directory create the file 'mariadb.conf' (as an example; any file should do) with the following:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
```

Run systemctl daemon-reload to reload the configuration and restart mariadb.

You should be able to create backups now.

Comment: Additional information. Apparently mysqldump doesn't like writing to /tmp or /var/tmp directories. If you switch the backups to a different directory such as /opt/mysqlbackup, it will work without changing the mariadb configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change `"some/folder"` to an external location. Looks like there were permission problems because originally the folder mentioned was under Perforce root and probably it had read-only permissions.

I then changed the new folder permissions to:

`mylinuxuser:mysql`

making sure that both the user with which the process was started, as well as mysql server have permissions to write there. This is because the sql file is written from user's name and txt file is written from mysql server's name.

I also added my user to the `mysql` group.

Answer (score -1):

What has worked for me (in Windows), trying to export a file using:

```
SELECT  * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/documents/dumps' from file
```

1. MySQL Service properties --> Log on: take note account defined.
2. Directory C:\documents\dumps --> properties --> Security: account defined above needs read/write privileges

Comment: This is OS permission related issue